# creating multiple monogdb databases using shell script

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongo-shell

I am trying to create multiple mongodb databases using following shell script. where root has root access at mongodb instance level.   db_names.txt passes db names to be created.

```
cat dbcreate.sh          
for DB in 'cat /home/db_names.txt'       
do       
echo "use $DB" | mongo   -u root  -p root  --port 27017   
echo "db.createCollection(\"testcollection\");" | mongo   -u root -p root123 --port 27017 
done
```

But it is failing with following error:  I can't understand why root can't create collection in user database? can anyone help?

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.12
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("4e714db0-9faf-497c-ae4e-bbf913979bbd") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.12
switched to db db1
bye
exception: connect failed
MongoDB shell version v4.0.12
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("ed678cc0-9f8b-4935-859b-b02e039c8d47") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.12
switched to db db2
bye
```

Regards,
Var

Answer (score 0):

The script above initiates two Mongo shell clients, each running on Mongo command:

1) use $DB
2) db.createCollection(\"testcollection\")

You probably want to send both commands into the same Mongo shell, so that the db.createCollection will be executed in the correct database provided by use:

```
do
    ( echo "use $DB" | echo "db.createCollection(\"testcollection\");" ) |
        mongo -u root  -p root --port 27017   
done
```

Or similar.